# JAVA::CORBA NameComponent nameService.rebind results in an exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, corba

I got the following JAVA CORBA Server code which I am trying to debug.

Code snippet (not the all code) is below. The code is running without any problem. But, When I uncomment the "nameService.rebind(countName" I get the following exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException

It looks to me that the issue related to the countName array. Any idea what can cause to the Exception?

// bind the Count object in the Naming service

```
  NameComponent[] countName = new NameComponent [1000];
  for(int i=1;i<1000;i++){
      countName[i] = new NameComponent ("+i+", "");
  }
 // nameService.rebind(countName, 
 //         myPOA.servant_to_reference(countServant));

  System.out.println(myPOA.servant_to_reference(countServant)
        + " is ready.");
```

Comment: Do you have your `nameService` instantiated?

Comment: Yes. I think I do have instantiated here:

Comment: NamingContextExt nameService = 
           NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(nameServiceObj);
      if (nameService == null) 
      {
        System.out.println("nameService = null");
        return;
      }

Comment: To resolve this issue, I used the method to_name as follows: object[componentIndex]=nameService.to_name("MyObject"+componentIndex);

Comment: Please PROVIDE the full stacktrace and mark the lines

Answer (score 0):

Your NameComponent[0] is NULL here. Change the code to

```
NameComponent[] countName = new NameComponent [1000];
  for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
      countName[i] = new NameComponent ("+i+", "");
  }
```

In your code you starting your loop from 1 , but you should have started from 0